# The difference between community and moderators

Tags: discussion

Recently, there have been more-than-usual flags suggesting/implying that one question or another should be closed. Yet, I haven't been seeing any close votes or comments pointing out whatever the problem was - despite the fact that at least one flagger had the rep to cast a close vote. Thus, I want to make something very clear: **moderators deal with *exceptions***. At current count, there are 113 people, 6 of whom are mods, that have at least 500 rep and [can vote to close a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation). Any question only needs *5* close votes from the community, far less than 108.

This has been said in various ways before, but let me say it again. If you think a question needs work, edit. If you don't feel like you can edit it without making drastic changes to meaning and such, post a comment. If you think it's unsalvageable or just doesn't fit on this site, vote to close. Of course, there are other reasons for doing any of the above three actions, but you should get the gist.

Okay, rare semi-rant over. :P

Comment: I'd go as far as saying if you think the question needs significant work but aren't up for it yourself then go ahead and vote to close in that situation.